# KeyError in reading numbers from file

Tags: python

I'm trying to run this code

```
def calculate_metrics(GTS,RES):
    f = open("id.txt",'r')
    for imgId in f:
        gts[imgId] = imgToGTS[imgId]
        print(imgToGTS[imgId])
```

but got error in

```
gts[imgId] = imgToGTS[imgId]
KeyError: '16977'
```

id file contains like

```
16977
16977
16977
52087
6672
46378
16977
52087
```

EDIT

```
gts={}
imgToGTS = {ann['image_id']: [] for ann in datasetGTS['annotations']
for ann in datasetGTS['annotations']:
    imgToGTS[ann['image_id']] += [ann]
```

datasetGTS contains

```
{'info': {'description': 'COCO 2014 Dataset', 'url': 'http://cocodataset.org', 'version': '1.0', 'year': 2014, 'contributor': 'COCO Consortium', 'date_created': '2017/09/01'}, 'images': [{'license': 4, 'file_name': 'COCO_val2014_000000060623.jpg', 'coco_url': 'http://images.cocodataset.org/val2014/COCO_val2014_000000060623.jpg', 'height': 427, 'width': 640, 'date_captured': '2013-11-14 17:24:15', 'flickr_url': 'http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6080/6113512699_37b4c98473_z.jpg', 'id': 60623}
```

i tried to print `imgToGTS` and got

```
{16977: [], 52087: [], 6672: [], 46378: [], 57429: [], 5247: [], 12667: [], 22793: [], 27842: [], 61259: [], 5394: [], 59171: [], 32203: [], 65485: [], 11511: [], 31984: [], 40986:
```

Comment: I don't see any 'annotations' key in datasetGTS...

Answer (score 0):

you need to clean your input, right now it also has the end of line character. In this example, `key` will be the nice and clean key, while `imgId` will still have eol:

```
for imgId in f:
    key = imgId.strip()
    gts[key] = imgToGTS[key]
    print(imgToGTS[key])
```

Comment: excuse me where should i write it ? before for loop ?

Comment: do you mean f ? or imgId ?

Comment: updated the answer to fit your case

Comment: thanks i got KeyError: '42'

Comment: that just means it still doesn't exist. Could you post more of your code? Parts where you declare `imgToGTS` and `gts` to be more specific

Comment: please can you the update post

Comment: `datasetGTS` doesn't have `'annotations'`. Is that a mistake?